# Can I play sound from my computer on an Echo Dot?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

My computer speaker is terrible.  Can I set up so that if I play something on my computer, the sound comes out on my Echo Dot 3rd Generation?

Comment: "My Media for Alexa" it cost $5 a year and work.

Answer (score 6):

You might be able to pair your computer with the Dot [using Bluetooth](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=202011860):

> To pair your mobile device with Echo Dot:
>
> 1. Open the Alexa app.
> 2. Open the left navigation panel, and then select Settings.
> 3. Select your Echo Dot, and then select Bluetooth > Pair a New Device. Your Echo Dot enters pairing mode.
> 4. Open the Bluetooth settings menu on your mobile device, and select your Echo Dot. It may take a few seconds for your Echo Dot to appear in the list. Alexa then tells you if the connection is successful.
>
> **Tip:** The next time you want to connect your mobile device to your Echo Dot, turn on Bluetooth on you mobile device, and then say, "Connect." If you have multiple Bluetooth devices paired with your Echo Dot, Echo Dot connects to the most recent device.

If your computer doesn't have a built-in Bluetooth radio, you could try buying a cheap Bluetooth dongle to connect to your computer via USB.

Note that for step 4, you'll need to find the Bluetooth settings for your OS. For Windows, [guides are available on the Microsoft website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/15290/windows-connect-bluetooth-device) — follow the instructions for a Bluetooth speaker, because that's essentially what the Dot is in this case.